# TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable during clustering

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am implementing the KMeans algorithm for clustering and i get this problem and its not working in jupyter platform. I am applying elbow method to find the optimal number of clusters.

```
#Now find the optimal number of clusters using elbow method
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
wcss = []
for i in range[1,11]:
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', max_iter = 300, n_init = 10, random_state = 0)
    kmeans.fit(X)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
plt.plot(range(1,11), wcss)
plt.title('The Elbow Method')
plt.xlabel('Number of Clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------

    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-31-ebfededa579e> in <module>()
          2 from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
          3 wcss = []
    ----> 4 for i in range[1,11]:
          5     kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++', max_iter = 300, n_init = 10, random_state = 0)
          6     kmeans.fit(X)

    TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: i was facing a similar  error , after some debugging found that I was trying - kmeans = KMeans[x] instead of kmeans = KMeans(x)

Answer (score 0):

The error says (or tries to say) that `range` is a method. Therefore you need to call it like this: `range(1, 11)` instead of `range[1, 11]`.

If you change this in the 4th line it should work (at least this part).